# sendto error: Invalid argument

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I got trouble on using `sendto()` function in socket

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int acceptFd;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;
    char recieveBuf[512];
    char sendBuf[512];
    socklen_t cliLen;

    if(-1 == (acceptFd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0))) perror("socket() failed.\n");
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(6789);
    if(-1==bind(acceptFd,(struct sockaddr*)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr))) perror("bind() failed.\n");


    bzero(&cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr));

    while(1){


        if(recvfrom(acceptFd, recieveBuf, 512, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &cliaddr, &cliLen) == -1) {
            perror("recvfrom() failed");
            continue;
        }

        strcpy(sendBuf,"recieved\n");
        printf("%s\n",sendBuf);
        if(-1 == sendto(acceptFd,sendBuf, 512,0,(struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr,cliLen)){
            perror("sendto() failed");
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

the `recvfrom()` works fine, but every time `sendto()` was called, the error handling print out this: `sendto() failed: Invalid argument`

the send program is here:

```
#include "test.AcceptMessage.pb.h"
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {



    int sendSocket;
    struct sockaddr_in cliaddr;
    char buf[512];
    if(-1 == (sendSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0))) perror("socket() failed.\n");
    bzero(&cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr));
    cliaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    cliaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    cliaddr.sin_port = htons(6789);

    sendto(sendSocket,buf, 512,0,(
            struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr));



    recvfrom(sendSocket,buf,512,0, nullptr, nullptr);
    printf("%s\n",buf);





    return 0;
}
```

So what's wrong with this code?

Comment: change cliLen in the call to **sendto(2)** to `sizeof (struct sockaddr_in)` or `sizeof cliaddr`.  Probably the system call automatic checking is invalidating the parameter size you pass to the kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man recvfrom`:

> Before the call, it [addrlen] should be initialized to the size of the
>          buffer  associated  with  src_addr.

Therefore, initialize your `cliLen` variable with:

```
socklen_t cliLen = sizeof(cliaddr);
```

Comment: This did works, but I'm cruise that why: if I already know the length of the sockaddr, why bother to get the length any way?

Comment: From `man recvfrom`: "The returned address is
       truncated  if  the  buffer provided is too small; in this case, `addrlen`
       will return a value greater than was supplied to the call." This means `addrlen` indicates potential buffer overflows.

Comment: thanks so much, seems that I should read the API doc more careful.

Comment: @reavenisadesk, not.  You don't know.  you have changed `cliLen` in the call to `recvefrom`, so you lost the value.  The system call interface to the kernel expects fixed sizes to pass to the kernel, but when returning from it you can get a different value for the size returned in the `struct sockaddr_in` structure, to allow you to improve storage.  If you check the structure definition, you'll find padding on the structure (not being accounted for in the returning from kernel side, but needed in the system call parameter checking)

Comment: @LuisColorado yes, the cliLen was init at first, but changed each time recvfrom calls, right?

Comment: @reavenisadesk, when you receive the `struct sockaddr_in`  from kernel space, you receive it trimmed to the actual size of the address (so you don't get the space used by the padding array at the end).  When you have to pass it to the kernel, you need to use `sizeof (struct sockaddr_in)` as it is statically checked on the system call interface for the `sendto(2)` call.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any reason to use `recvfrom()` and `sendto()` at all here. It's a connected socket. Just use `send()` and `recv().`